# Slow loading Libsvm on android phone

Tags: android, java-native-interface, libsvm

I am trying to load a libsvm model on an android phone. The model is about 3MB, but it takes about 20s to load this model file which is not acceptable for a small App. I am using the libsvm official Java API to load it from my internal storage.

PS: I am trying to use libsvm c++ API to load this model via JNI too. but I meet the following problem:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ca_uwo_csd_Threads_FoodRecgNativeLib_loadsvm
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jstring path)
{
    const char* path_char = env->GetStringUTFChars(path,0);//path is correct!
    LOGI(TAG,"Loading start");
    svm_model* model = svm_load_model(path_char); // fatal signal 11 here!!!
    LOGI(TAG,"Loading OK");
}
```

If I comment the load model line, everything goes well. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried loading smaller models? What time does it take? As I remember, SVM model file is a text file, so parsing it may consume quite a bit of time on a weak device such as phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. Calling C++ loading function svm_load_model() via JNI is much faster than Java version(444ms in my case). The fatal signal 11 error happens at

```
char *old_locale = strdup(setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL));
setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
```

and any other places that call the parameter and function in svm.cpp file (like free the points to it). So comment these and loading file will work.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Because setlocale() on Android returns NULL. There is a pull request that fixed this bug, but it's not merged into the trunk yet. See https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/pull/20